# Can I charge my AC rechargeable hearing aid batteries via USB PD with converter?

Tags: usb, battery-charging, charging, usb-c, usb-pd

I hope you'll be able to help. First of all this is a bit of a complex one that I'm struggling with. I wear hearing aids, both of which use removable, rechargeable batteries, charged only by a charger plugged into an AC outlet.

Short version: I'm looking to try and see if it's possible to charge my batteries using a USB outlet, presumably USB C or USB PD (meaning I can use a battery bank to do so, and I don't have to spend my life tethered to an AC outlet).

Long version: I'm profoundly deaf, (basically, without hearing aids I hear sod all) and I'm an outdoor person. I love to spend long periods of time outdoors, exploring and doing things that involved a prolonged period of time away from regular AC outlets. This means that I don't always get to recharge my hearing aid batteries due to their power supply being AC (UK plug). Hearing aid manufacturers aren't renowned for being modern and keeping up to date with modern charging capabilities. I'd love to know if it's possible to charge my current set up using a USB C/USB PD battery bank, with the help of an adapter/converter; I just simply don't know enough about electronics to feel comfortable in making the decision. I swear to God, if anyone is able to help me understand this or make it possible, you will have honestly changed my life and I'll be forever grateful to you.

The specifications on the plug for the charger to my hearing aid batteries reads as follows:
Switching Power Supply
Model: S018BAM1200100
Input: 100-240V ~ 50/60Hz 500mA
Output: 12V - 1000mA

If there's any more information you need, just let me know. Again, I appreciate anyone's help with this in any way.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use a regular 12V 1A battery bank for this. Plenty of those available, unless the hearing aids have some proprietary plug?

Comment: What kind of hearing aid batteries do you have that need 1-A charging supply? Just curious...

Comment: Detachable cochlear implant batteries :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M7Z9Z1N) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00935L44E) should work just fine for you (but see the entire lineup, you might like different model more).

The only problem with 12V power banks is that they tend to be rather on heavy side, which can be a burden while hiking.

I think you should also explore solar power alternative. While [smaller solar panels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D2SPZAM) won't be able to provide 1A charging current they still should be able to charge hearing aid battery. But even [bigger panels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y5YNVLH) are often lighter than 12V power banks. And you can hang them on your backpack and charge on the go.

Finally there are combination power bank + solar panel models. These are heavy but versatile. Many of them have built-in LED light and rugged body, which is extremely useful outdoors.

UPDATE

If you want to reuse your existing power bank, there are DC-DC "boost" modules that can convert 5V into 12V. Like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-DC-Adjustable-Step-Up-Power-Converter-Adjustable-Voltage-Regulator-Module-Board-3V-5V-12V-Turn/32704164127.html) or [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/J34-Free-Shipping-DC-DC-2A-Booster-Board-Step-up-Module-Input-2-24V-to-5/32398978815.html) for example. They are cheap and they work. However keep in mind, that inside your power bank there is DC-DC already, producing 5V from battery voltage. This dual conversion reduces efficiency of the power bank. The bank with 12V output does this conversion only once.

Furthermore, to get 1A at 12V you need to draw at least 2.5A from 5V power bank. You need to make sure yours can provide this much. And you can calculate how long it can do that. For example 8,000 mAh bank can give you only 3 hours charging. If this is enough for your needs then OK.

This is the reason I suggested solar power in the first place. When you have no way to recharge power bank on a long trip you are back to square one. But if you have solar panel you do not need to worry. So, check out combination devices too ([one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073P5D9KD), [two](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SFO4WUW)). At least with them using converter module makes more sense, despite efficiency loss.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your feedback. I’ll have a look into those.8 guess because I’m already using battery banks to charge my iPhone etc and some of the battery banks have usb PD (which I’m aware can deliver up to 100w output in some cases) it seems silly that I can’t utilise that in some way. Is there no converter/adapter that would be possible to convert the power delivered by this USB PD socket to the appropriate output needed by the charger?

Comment: Yes, it is easy to reuse your existing power bank. See an update in the answer.

Comment: A solar panel is not great advice.  A solar panel needs a battery and MPPT charger to store the energy.  You cannot connect a solar panel directly to the hearing aid charger.  A 12V panel does not output 12V.  Voltage ranges from 0 to 20+ volts depending on the amount of irradiation received.

Comment: @Misunderstood First, you do not need "MPPT charger" if MPPT is built into panel itself, as is the case with [Goal Zero](https://www.goalzero.com/blog/from-the-engineers-the-nomad-7-plus/) devices I linked to. Second, the combination devices I suggested provide power form the battery, not solar panel. They output exact voltage they are designed for.

Comment: Okay you got me there.  I did not follow your link and assumed you were referring to just a solar panel.  Still when an inexpensive small (e.g. four 18650 cells) fully charged battery pack will do the job well for an extended period of time, a solar panel is a superfluous waste of money.  Especially on a cloudy day.

Comment: This sounds good- at the moment I have a 26,000ma battery bank and another 20,000 one  above suggestions should be awesome. I get what you’re saying about solar power- I’m actually looking at buying a portable folding 20w one that can recharge my banks on the go.

Comment: Again, I really Appreciate your help on this guys. Thanks @Maple too, appreciate it!

Comment: @Misunderstood Normally I would agree with you, I am not a big fan of solar power. However OP's situation is quite specific with long outdoor trips. Even huge power banks eventually run out of juice, and they are quite heavy. I don't know power source other than solar available in the woods.

Comment: @Maple in fact, inspired by your suggestions I got searching and I found this, would this do the trick too? Step Up Converter,Qutaway 5V To 12V USB Step Up Voltage Transformer DC Power Cable With Barrel Jack Booster Module(5V-12V) https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B071X6VYXR/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_7JhCBbG7V33BC

Comment: Nice device that eliminates the need to attach plugs yourself. But it is only 0.8A, which means you will not be charging as fast as you could (that is, if your charger will work with it at all). See if you can find similar device with at least 1A. Or use the modules like the ones in my links, capable of 3A output at 5V input.

Comment: My only concern with the ones you’ve suggested is they seem a bit open and exposed- wouldn’t feel as comfortable rattling it about in a back pack charging :/

Comment: @H.Thomas The Amazon step up regulator is a good choice for a 5V battery pack.  It will work with a non-regulated 5V battery back.  It says it will work with as little as a 2V input.

Comment: The DIY modules are not designed to be used as is. The DIY part includes attaching wires and placing them into enclosure of your choice. If that is too much trouble then look for the ready-made devices as the one you've found.

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but I'm not going to be camping away from my car or Harley for extended periods of time.  But if I were inclined to be away from my car too long I am going to bring lots of Li-ion battery power.  At a minimum I'm going to bring an LED lamp, phone, mobile tablet with LTE, and enough LI-ion to keep them powered the entire trip away for the car.  When I get a hearing aid not sure where it will rank in priority to the aforementioned devices.  These days my idea of getting back to nature is putting the top down on my Camero SS2   convertible.

Comment: Ha, I see where that comes from. Trust me, when you get a hearing aid hauling couple kilos of batteries is much less appealing than 30 years before that. I recently found myself subconsciously swapping telephoto DSLR for compact zoom just to keep the backpack a bit lighter. Bringing tablet along would not even cross my mind

Comment: I agree, I like to escape the technology and dependence we have on social networking and phones when I go- the whole reason I enjoy it. But I also love a few geeky outdoor gadgets myself, ie just bought myself a camping stove that charges a battery/USB socket from the heat generated off the fire when in use. Love it! Photography is the main thing though. Nearly all DSLR batteries (at least the older style ones I use anyway) need ac socket to charge. There’s also something pretty special about sitting in a tent when it’s hammering down with rain, with a film on a tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Any regulated 12V battery or battery pack will work fine.  Your car battery with a cigarette lighter adapter would be ideal.

You will still need the charger. The 1000 mA spec on the power supply is more than sufficient to power the charger.  You can very likely use a battery with less than a 1000 mA output.  I manufactured a product that used about 300 mA but included a 1000 mA supply because it was the same cost as a lower current supply and more readily available. I did not use it because the device required 1000 mA. That said 1000 mA is easily achieved by most 12V Li-ion battery packs.

If away from your car for extended periods of time, if your battery bank is a regulated 12V it will work fine. By regulated I mean it outputs 12V regardless of the battery voltage.

If you need to purchase a new battery pack I would recommend one that uses 4 18650 batteries with a buck/boost (step down/step up) regulated 12V output so no matter where the battery voltages are in their discharge cycle, they will provide a 12V output.  Many battery packs charge up to their maximum voltage then discharge to a much lower cutoff voltage and therefore would be of limited use.  Just because a battery pack is labeled 12V (nominal) does not mean it outputs 12V.

Depending on your type of battery you may be able to take some spare primary (non-rechargeable) with you.

Thanks for the question.  I may need a hearing aid soon with about 70% loss.  I cannot watch a movie without closed captioning.  I now know to choose a hearing aid that uses both primary and secondary (rechargeable) batteries. But for now I can usually get away with smiling and nodding my head.

Comment: Glad I can be of help in return- another piece of advice, look for one that is at least splashproof. Getting caught out in the rain or having an unexpected splash of water is so taken for granted.

Comment: I believe the OP does have the charger. The 12 V 1 A is an input to his charger, if I understand the situation correctly. So any simple 12-V battery pack will do the job, he just need a proper cable.

Comment: @AliChen yes I agree.  I was saying his charger likely does not need for the battery to provide a full amp.  It's just that a 1 amp power supply is the easiest for the manufacturer as far as cost and inventory control.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas,

I have the exact same problem as you are having. I cannot live my life knowing I'll be forever constrained to a wall outlet to charge my hearing aid device. I even contacted Cochlear about this and they said do it at your own risk.

I performed a electrical test of how much wattage the battery charger consumes (Not using the USB port that the base station have). I have estimated that the battery consume roughly 0.6 to 0.7 watts which will consume 2.4 ~ 2.5 watts for all four batteries at once. (Currently I only have three batteries to test with, but I did test how much wattage it consume per each batteries at a time). The max total, including the base station, would take about 2.6~2.7 watts for four batteries.

My estimation would be that a simple 5v 1a (Should provide 5 watts) USB bank should be sufficient to charge the battery for four hours. The charger based does require a initial idle power of 0.3 watt.

I do plan on building a small USB power converter to meet the necessary requirement specification to charge just the battery itself. I do need help figuring out where I could buy the outlet for the charger base station. Once I figure that out, I'll assemble a quick and simple USB to power port jack to power the device.

If I can get all of this working, I'd be glad to share this solution with you! Hope the information above helps!